# Как создавать кнопки с помощью цикла While?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Всегда было интересно, как можно создать несколько кнопок с помощью цикла While.
К примеру, нужно создать пять кнопок в рандомным местоположением:

```
self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
self.button1.resize(50, 50)
self.button1.move(random.randint(1, 50), random.randint(1, 50))
```

И такое приходится писать для каждой кнопки. Но как это можно реализовать с помощью циклов (возможно не только While)? У меня всегда возникали проблемы с переменными и я бросал эту идею. Возможно ли вобще такое реализовать?

---

**UPD.**

Заметил такой баг. Допустим, есть такой код.

```
for i_numb, i in enumerate(range(5)):
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
    button.resize(50, 50)
    button.move(random.randint(1, 50), random.randint(1, 50))
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: Function(i_numb))
```

По задумке, каждая из кнопок должна отправлять цифру от 0 до 4. Но, после исполнения, каждая кнопка будет отсылать цифру 4. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
self.buttons = []

for i in range(5):
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
    button.resize(50, 50)
    button.move(random.randint(1, 50), random.randint(1, 50))

    self.buttons.append(button)
```

---

> Но, после исполнения, каждая кнопка будет отсылать цифру 4.

Просто, в текущем виде, в лямбду будет записано последнее значение цикла, правильно поместить значение в атрибут лямбды:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda i_numb=i_numb: Function(i_numb))
```

---

**PS.**

Список `self.buttons` не обязательный

Comment: но ведь невозможно создать несколько переменных с одинаковым именем button

Comment: Можно, достаточно вам запустить код и увидеть что это работает. Это не имя, а переменная, которая будет хранить ссылку на объект QPushButton. Также ссылку на этот объект будет хранить родитель -- self.frame (и self.buttons)

Comment: Но как тогда обращаться к кнопке по self.frame?

Comment: И можно ли с помощью цикла for удалить все объекты, находящиеся в self.frame? Была бы очень полезная функция

Comment: все объекты или все добавленные вами кнопки? если объекты, тогда через метод findChildren находите виджеты и вызываете у них deleteLater. Если через список, то перебираете виджеты в списке и тоже вызываете deleteLater. Если не понятно, то создайте вопрос по этой теме (и например напишите сюда мне ссылку на вопрос)

Comment: Пожалуй, лучше напишу еще вопрос для будущих поколений

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847369/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, но нажимается только первая созданная кнопка. Что за баги?

Comment: После `button.move` добавьте и `button.clicked.connect(<ваш метод>`

Comment: Так и сделал. Результата ноль

Comment: Все понял. Там был еще один фрейм выше фрейма кнопки и он не давал на нее нажать.

Comment: Молодцы, что сами разобрались :)

Comment: Сейчас обнаружил один баг в данном коде. Добавлю в вопрос код и объяснение. Никак не могу понять с чем то связано и как это решить

Comment: @Evilenzo, эммм давайте посмотрим

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Evilenzo, не согласен, что это бага моего кода. А по поводу проблемы, это "фишка", на которую не только вы натыкались :) Попробуйте так: `button.clicked.connect(lambda x=i_numb: Function(x))`

Comment: Почему-то теперь функция получает просто False

Comment: При нажатии любой кнопки

Comment: Слепое программирование оно такое :) давайте еще раз: `button.clicked.connect(lambda checked=None, x=i_numb: Function(x))`

Comment: Все заработало :) Кстати, как возможно с вами связаться?

Comment: @Evilenzo, у меня есть в профили ссылки, по ссылкам есть и другие ссылки и т.д. Но если вы новичек с кучей вопросов по Qt, то лучше на форум идите, я одно время до стека (с 2012 года) сидел на русскоязычном qt форуме: http://www.prog.org.ru/index.php

Comment: Да я уже не считаю себя прям сильно новичком. Просто есть множество моментов, ответов на которые нет в интернете