# Как удалить все объекты, находящиеся во фрейме

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Можно ли с помощью циклов удалить все объекты, находящиеся во фрейме?

Comment: не проще просто фрейм скрыть?

Comment: @Twiss нет. Тогда в одной области придется плодить несколько фреймов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот ответ логическое продолжение [другого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847291/201445).

Можно хранить в своем списке и если нужно удалить, перебрать элементы в списке и вызывать у них [deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import random


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttons = []

        self.button_fill = Qt.QPushButton('Fill')
        self.button_fill.clicked.connect(self.on_fill)

        self.button_clear = Qt.QPushButton('Clear')
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.on_clear)

        self.frame = Qt.QFrame()

        main_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_fill)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.button_clear)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def on_fill(self):
        for i in range(5):
            button = Qt.QPushButton(self.frame)
            button.resize(50, 50)
            button.move(random.randint(1, 300), random.randint(1, 300))
            button.show()

            self.buttons.append(button)

    def on_clear(self):
        print('Button ({}): {}'.format(len(self.buttons), self.buttons))

        for button in self.buttons:
            button.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = Widget()
    mw.resize(400, 400)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

**Второй способ** сделать поиск детей-виджетов через [findChildren](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) и у каждого вызвать [deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater)`.

Тот же код, но без `self.buttons` и с измененным `on_clear`:

```
def on_clear(self):
    buttons = self.frame.findChildren(Qt.QPushButton)

    print('Button ({}): {}'.format(len(buttons), buttons))

    for button in buttons:
        button.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду чуть-чуть другое. Как удалять именно объекты, которые созданы, к примеру, в Qt Designer

Comment: Варианты: 1) Удалять из дизайнера 2) Удалять из ui-файла 3) Программное удаление (его я показал вам), поиск через findChildren

Comment: @Evilenzo, такие детали стоит указывать в вопросе

Comment: Теперь исчерпывающе

Comment: @MaxU суть была не именно в дизайнере, а в кнопках, которые не были внесены в список